# Scale table column by maximum text content

Tags: html, css

I want to make my table columns to scale by text content of the max-length row in a column, like this:

[image]

The problem is that I have used flex for this, and changed the order of `tr`, `th`, `td`, `table` tags:

Css file:

```
.table {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

React file:

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './App.module.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <table className={styles.table}>
      <tr className={styles.tr}>
        <th className={styles.td}>Company</th>
        <td className={styles.td}> Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td className={styles.td}>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      </tr>
      <tr className={styles.tr}>
        <th className={styles.td}>Contact</th>
        <td className={styles.td}>Maria Anders</td>
        <td className={styles.td}>Francisco Chang</td>
      </tr>
      <tr className={styles.tr}>
        <th className={styles.td}>Country</th>
        <td className={styles.td}>Mexico</td>
        <td className={styles.td}>UK</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is there way to implement same functionality, but without destroying converntional table structure (I am concerned it may afffect accessibility).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a basic table without using flex be enough to achieve what you're looking for?

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```